# Updating a @Published variable based on changes in an observed variable

Tags: swift, combine

I have an AppState that can be observed:

```
class AppState: ObservableObject {

    private init() {}
    static let shared = AppState()

    @Published fileprivate(set) var isLoggedIn = false

}
```

A View Model should decide which view to show based on the state (`isLoggedIn`):

```swift
class HostViewModel: ObservableObject, Identifiable {

    enum DisplayableContent {
        case welcome
        case navigationWrapper
    }

    @Published var containedView: DisplayableContent = AppState.shared.isLoggedIn ? .navigationWrapper : .welcome

}
```

In the end a `HostView` observes the `containedView` property and displays the correct view based on it.

My problem is that `isLoggedIn` is not being observed with the code above and I can't seem to figure out a way to do it. I'm quite sure that there is a simple way, but after 4 hours of trial & error I hope the community here can help me out.

Comment: `AppState.shared.isLoggedIn` — to access current value of `isLoggedIn`, `AppState.shared.$isLoggedIn` — to access updating published value.

Comment: @user28434 thanks, but I already checked that and it results in an error: "'Published<Bool>.Publisher' is not convertible to 'Bool'"

Comment: It is not, but you can map over it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Working solution:**

After two weeks of working with Combine I have now reworked my previous solution again (see edit history) and this is the best I could come up with now. It's still not exactly what I had in mind, because `contained` is not subscriber and publisher at the same time, but I think the `AnyCancellable` is always needed. If anyone knows a way to achieve my vision, please still let me know.

```swift
class HostViewModel: ObservableObject, Identifiable {

    @Published var contained: DisplayableContent
    private var containedUpdater: AnyCancellable?

    init() {
        self.contained = .welcome
        setupPipelines()
    }

    private func setupPipelines() {
        self.containedUpdater = AppState.shared.$isLoggedIn
            .map { $0 ? DisplayableContent.mainContent : .welcome }
            .assign(to: \.contained, on: self)
    }

}

extension HostViewModel {

    enum DisplayableContent {
        case welcome
        case mainContent
    }

}
```

Comment: This solution introduces a retain cycle. The `HostViewModel` will never be released unless you manually set the `containedUpdater` property to `nil`. See my answer below for a solution that avoids a retain cycle.

Answer (score 3):

> **DISCLAIMER**:
>
> It is not full solution to the problem, it won't trigger `objectWillChange`, so it's useless for `ObservableObject`. But it may be useful for some related problems.

Main idea is to create `propertyWrapper` that will update property value on change in linked `Publisher`:

```
@propertyWrapper
class Subscribed<Value, P: Publisher>: ObservableObject where P.Output == Value, P.Failure == Never {
    private var watcher: AnyCancellable?

    init(wrappedValue value: Value, _ publisher: P) {
        self.wrappedValue = value
        watcher = publisher.assign(to: \.wrappedValue, on: self)
    }

    @Published
    private(set) var wrappedValue: Value {
        willSet {
            objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }

    private(set) lazy var projectedValue = self.$wrappedValue
}
```

Usage:

```
class HostViewModel: ObservableObject, Identifiable {

    enum DisplayableContent {
        case welcome
        case navigationWrapper
    }

    @Subscribed(AppState.shared.$isLoggedIn.map({ $0 ? DisplayableContent.navigationWrapper : .welcome }))
    var contained: DisplayableContent = .welcome

    // each time `AppState.shared.isLoggedIn` changes, `contained` will change it's value
    // and there's no other way to change the value of `contained`
}
```

Comment: This looks very nice, but is limited to shared objects, singletons, such as `AppState`. It is not possible to do `@Subscribed(appStateInMyProperty.$isLoggedIn)` because `Cannot use instance member 'appStateInMyProperty' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

Answer (score 2):

When you add an `ObservedObject` to a View, SwiftUI adds a receiver for the `objectWillChange` publisher and you need to do the same. As `objectWillChange` is sent before `isLoggedIn` changes it might be an idea to add a publisher that sends in its `didSet`. As you are interested in the initial value as well as changes a `CurrentValueSubject<Bool, Never>` is probably best. In your `HostViewModel` you then need to subscribe to `AppState`'s new publisher and update `containedView` using the published value. Using `assign` can cause reference cycles so `sink` with a weak reference to `self` is best.

No code but it is very straight forward. The last trap to look out for is to save the returned value from `sink` to an `AnyCancellable?` otherwise your subscriber will disappear.

Comment: (Code Format in Comments is bad, sorry for the inconvenience) Thanks for your suggestion, I had something like this already yesterday and it looks like this in the HostViewModel: `var contained: DisplayableContent = .welcome` and `var test = AppState.shared.$isLoggedIn.sink { isLoggedIn in contained = isLoggedIn ? .navigationWrapper : .welcome }` The problem then is that I can't set `contained` from `sink`: Instance member 'contained' cannot be used on type 'HostViewModel'

Comment: Update: I solved it with parts of your answer and a few more articles online. I will update my question with the solution I found.

Answer (score 2):

A generic solution for subscribing to changes of `@Published` variables in embedded `ObservedObject`s is to pass `objectWillChange` notifications to the parent object.

Example:

```
import Combine

class Parent: ObservableObject {

  @Published
  var child = Child()

  var sink: AnyCancellable?

  init() {
    sink = child.objectWillChange.sink(receiveValue: objectWillChange.send)
  }
}

class Child: ObservableObject {
  @Published
  var counter: Int = 0

  func increase() {
    counter += 1
  }
}
```

Demo use with SwiftUI:

```
struct ContentView: View {

  @ObservedObject
  var parent = Parent()

  var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 50) {
      Text( "\(parent.child.counter)")
      Button( action: parent.child.increase) {
        Text( "Increase")
      }
    }
  }
}
```