# Published computed properties in SwiftUI model objects

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

Suppose I have a data model in my SwiftUI app that looks like the following:

```
class Tallies: Identifiable, ObservableObject {
  let id = UUID()
  @Published var count = 0
}

class GroupOfTallies: Identifiable, ObservableObject {
  let id = UUID()
  @Published var elements: [Tallies] = []
}
```

I want to add a computed property to `GroupOfTallies` that resembles the following:

```
// Returns the sum of counts of all elements in the group
var cumulativeCount: Int {
  return elements.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.count }
}
```

However, I want SwiftUI to update views when the `cumulativeCount` changes. This would occur either when `elements` changes (the array gains or loses elements) or when the `count` field of any contained `Tallies` object changes.

I have looked into representing this as an `AnyPublisher`, but I don't think I have a good enough grasp on Combine to make it work properly. This was mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58203531/an-equivalent-to-computed-properties-using-published-in-swift-combine), but the AnyPublisher created from it is based on a published `Double` rather than a published `Array`. If I try to use the same approach without modification, `cumulativeCount` only updates when the elements array changes, but not when the `count` property of one of the elements changes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are multiple issues here to address.

First, it's important to understand that SwiftUI updates the view's body when it detects a change, either in a `@State` property, or from an `ObservableObject` (via `@ObservedObject` and `@EnvironmentObject` property wrappers).

In the latter case, this is done either via a `@Published` property, or manually with `objectWillChange.send()`. `objectWillChange` is an `ObservableObjectPublisher` publisher available on any `ObservableObject`.

This is a long way of saying that ***IF*** the change in a computed property is caused *together* with a change of any `@Published` property -  for example, when another element is added from somewhere:

```
elements.append(Talies())
```

**then there's no need to do anything else** - SwiftUI will recompute the view that observes it, and will read the new value of the computed property `cumulativeCount`.

---

Of course, if the `.count` property of one of the `Tallies` objects  changes, this would NOT cause a change in `elements`, because `Tallies` is a reference-type.

The best approach given your simplified example is actually to make it a value-type - a `struct`:

```
struct Tallies: Identifiable {
  let id = UUID()
  var count = 0
}
```

Now, a change in any of the `Tallies` objects would cause a change in `elements`, which will cause the view that "observes" it to get the now-new value of the computed property. Again, no extra work needed.

---

If you insist, however, that `Tallies` cannot be a value-type for whatever reason, then you'd need to listen to any changes in `Tallies` by subscribing to their `.objectWillChange` publishers:

```
class GroupOfTallies: Identifiable, ObservableObject {
   let id = UUID()
   @Published var elements: [Tallies] = [] {
      didSet {
         cancellables = [] // cancel the previous subscription
         elements.publisher
            .flatMap { $0.objectWillChange }
            .sink(receiveValue: self.objectWillChange.send) 
            .store(in: &cancellables)
      }
   }

   private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>

   var cumulativeCount: Int {
     return elements.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.count } // no changes here
   }
}
```

The above will subscribe a change in the `elements` array (to account for additions and removals) by:

- converting the array into a `Sequence` publisher of each array element
- then flatMap again each array element, which is a `Tallies` object, into its `objectWillChange` publisher
- then for any output, call `objectWillChange.send()`, to notify of the view that observes it of its own changes.

Comment: This but you'll also need to sink elements that you add later.

Comment: @CasperZandbergen is your comment about the last approach? What do you mean by sink elements that you add later? If anything, the problem is that with every addition, this would duplicate publishers. I fixed it, I think. Ultimately, the last approach isn't the way I'd recommend solving OP's problem - just here for completeness

Comment: The data store I'm using relies on using objects, so the approach you mention at the end seems like the best way to solve this problem.

Comment: The solution has a retain cycle though, `GroupOfTallies` will never be released unless `elements` is manually set to `[]`. The `.sink` closure needs a `[weak self]` annotation.

Answer (score 3):

This is similar to the last option of `@New Dev`s answer, but a little shorter, essentially just passing the `objectWillChange` notification to the parent object:

```
import Combine

class Tallies: Identifiable, ObservableObject {
  let id = UUID()
  @Published var count = 0

  func increase() {
    count += 1
  }
}

class GroupOfTallies: Identifiable, ObservableObject {
  let id = UUID()
  var sinks: [AnyCancellable] = []
  
  @Published var elements: [Tallies] = [] {
    didSet {
      sinks = elements.map {
        $0.objectWillChange.sink( receiveValue: objectWillChange.send)
      }
    }
  }

  var cumulativeCount: Int {
    return elements.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.count }
  }
}
```

SwiftUI Demo:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @ObservedObject
  var group: GroupOfTallies

  init() {
    let group = GroupOfTallies()
    group.elements.append(contentsOf: [Tallies(), Tallies()])
    self.group = group
  }

  var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 50) {
      Text( "\(group.cumulativeCount)")
      Button( action: group.elements.first!.increase) {
        Text( "Increase first")
      }
      Button( action: group.elements.last!.increase) {
        Text( "Increase last")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest & fastest is to use value-type model.

Here is a simple demo. Tested & worked with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

```
struct TestTallies: View {
    @StateObject private var group = GroupOfTallies()     // SwiftUI 2.0
//    @ObservedObject private var group = GroupOfTallies()     // SwiftUI 1.0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Cumulative: \(group.cumulativeCount)")
            Divider()
            Button("Add") { group.elements.append(Tallies(count: 1)) }
            Button("Update") { group.elements[0].count = 5 }
        }
    }
}

struct Tallies: Identifiable {       // << make struct !!
  let id = UUID()
  var count = 0
}

class GroupOfTallies: Identifiable, ObservableObject {
  let id = UUID()
  @Published var elements: [Tallies] = []

    var cumulativeCount: Int {
      return elements.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.count }
    }
}
```